# How to read data in batches using JDBI?

Tags: kotlin, jdbc, cockroachdb, jdbi

I want to read all data from a table. The table has 4 million rows with 25 column in each row. I am setting fetch size to 1_000 to not overload JVM with lots of data. But the query itself is failing with timeout exception.

Does JDBI provide a "cursor" which can read data in batches thus avoid statement timeout? Is there any other way with JDBI to read this JDBI without statement timeout?

Code:

```
 var handle = jdbi.open()
 handle
   .createQuery("SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE")
   .setFetchSize(1_000)
   .mapToMap()
```

Exception:

```
query execution canceled due to statement timeout [statement:"SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE", arguments:{positional:{}, named:{}, finder:[]}]
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.SqlStatement.internalExecute(SqlStatement.java:1796)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultProducers.lambda$getResultSet$2(ResultProducers.java:64)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultIterable.lambda$of$0(ResultIterable.java:57)
    at org.jdbi.v3.core.result.ResultIterable.iterator(ResultIterable.java:43)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try using a smaller fetch size.

If that doesn't work, you can try doing pagination in your application code. Check out the docs on this here: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/pagination.html

Lastly, what is your statement_timeout set to? Can you raise it?

Have you tested on a smaller table? What is the largest table you can load without timing out?